# How to add another domain address to a wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-admin

I'm trying to add another domain address to a wordpress website.I have access to the dashboard but no access to the cpanel.
 my question is If i can't access the cpanel to add the address , is there another way to do it with a certain plugin ?

thank you

Comment: If you explain in more detail why you need to do this we might be abke to provide some suggestions. As it stands now, your question is a bit vague.

Answer (score 0):

If you are changing your site address and have access to the domain and the websites ip address you can point a domain to your site. 
you then will need to change your wordpress address url and site url 
[image]

in general>>settings to your updated domain, if these are greyed out thats due to your domain being set up in wp-config this will be a little more complex to update with out ftp or direct file access but not impossible

if greyed out you could install a plugin like wp file manager to allow dashboard access to you wp-config and edit your site address

```
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com' );
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com' );
```

read more [here](https://wordpress.org/support/article/changing-the-site-url/)

You really should be editing wordpress address url and site url via your database but without cpanel access i guess you cant.

you may need to update permalinks after the change.

If you are just adding an extra domain just to point it to the same place just edit the A records on you domain account to point to the sites ip